# Getting multiple users to guess the number discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
@commands.command()
  async def gtn(self, ctx):
    for guess in range(0, 5):
      await ctx.send('guess')
      number = random.randint(1,10)
      response = await self.client.wait_for('message')
      guess = int(response.content)
      if guess == number:
        await ctx.send('correct')
```

So this is my code, I want multiple users to guess the number and have unlimited chances but I'm not too sure how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop

```py
@commands.command()
async def gtn(self, ctx):
    while True:
        await ctx.send('guess')
        number = random.randint(1,10) 
        response = await self.client.wait_for('message')
        guess = int(response.content)
        if guess == number:
            await ctx.send('correct')
            break
```

Comment: But I don't think this is what I asked. Multiple users as in many people trying to guess at the same time so you do need unlimited chances.

Comment: Then change the for loop to a while loop, I have no idea what is so hard for you.